# How can I programmatically create links to openai playground session with a given prompt?

Tags: hyperlink, openai-api

It would be useful for debugging if I could take a programmatically generated chatgpt conversation and display it in the playground.

There are tools to share Openai playground sessions from within the website - but can I create one programmatically.